# Are AWS availability zone labels the same across time/users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, subnet, availability-zone

I'm trying to colocate my AWS instance with a website which, according to them, is hosted on availability zone `ap-southeast-1c`.

I'm wondering if the `1c` designation is stable over time and across users? I recall reading somewhere a long time ago that it isn't, but I can't recall the source. If the designation isn't stable across time/users, how do I ensure that I've hosted within the same availabilty zone?

I'm given the following choices when creating the instance:

```
subnet-3dad4b75 | Default in ap-southeast-1b
subnet-bfaf02e6 | Default in ap-southeast-1c #the obvious choice, ONLY IF the 1c label is stable
subnet-dbc533bd | Default in ap-southeast-1a
```

Comment: Collocate by regions not availability zone.  So for you ap-southeast-1.

Comment: @myron-semack Isn't it better/faster that I colocate to BOTH the region AND availability zone (instead of just the region)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over time they're the same, but not across AWS account. From the [EC2 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html):

> To ensure that resources are distributed across the Availability Zones for a Region, we independently map Availability Zones to names for each AWS account. For example, the Availability Zone `us-east-1a` for your AWS account might not be the same location as `us-east-1a` for another AWS account.